# Multithreading in cython

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, cython

I have this code in cython which I wrote to run on **two threads but still it is running on a single thread.**

File:test.pxd

```
from libcpp.stack cimport stack
cdef float cyprint(double[:,:] x,int n) nogil
```

File:test.pyx

```
cdef float cyprint(double[:,:] x,int n) nogil:
    cdef int i
    cdef float s=0
    cdef stack[int] mystack
    s=x[0,0]
    s=x[0,1]
    s=x[1,0]
    s=x[1,1]
    for i in range(300000000):
        mystack.push(i)
        s+=0.2
    #print s
    cdef int a[10][10]
    return s
```

File: test1.pyx

```
import numpy as np
from cython.parallel import prange,parallel
cimport openmp
#cimport test
from test cimport cyprint

print "ahooooo"
cdef double[:,:] y=np.array([[0.1, 3.1], [2.1, 2.1]])
cdef int n=4
cdef int allo
cdef int i
for i in prange(n,nogil=True,num_threads=2):
    cyprint(y,2)
    allo=openmp.omp_get_num_threads()
```

Also I'm not sure if I'm compiling the code correct. So here's the setup.py

File: setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_module = Extension(
    "test",
    ["test.pyx","test1.pyx"],
    libraries=["m"],
    extra_compile_args = ["-O3", "-ffast-math", "-march=native", "-fopenmp" ],
    language="c++",
    extra_link_args=['-fopenmp']
)


setup(
    name = 'Hello world app',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = cythonize(ext_module),
)
```

This code runs the prange loop as it is without dividing the loop into multiple threads.Why is it happening?